# convert json utc "/Date(1420095600000-0700)/" date to nsdate

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdate, nsdateformatter, utc

I get date like "/Data(xxx....xxx-xxxx)" from api. How can i get nsdate form this format. Temporarily I solved this problem to truncate the string and get seconds. but I need proper solution for this problem. kindly help me

Comment: You only option is the spilt this string in to the correct components.
Like you have already done, you get the seconds and create a date from that. Then `-7000` is the timezone, you might want to set the correct timezone if needed.

Comment: -0700 ist not utc and there is no time zone -7000 :-)

Comment: @HermannKlecker Stupid typo, `-7000` should have been `-0700`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSDateFormater to transform this String (the parts within the brackets) into an NSDate and vice versa. See the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateFormatter/dateFormat and here about the various formating possibilities: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000029i

Well, you may have to get rid of the milliseconds.

Comment: thanks for answered me, i get server time as utc. it may be changed. so, i need for solution for this problem.

Comment: Extract the time, get rid of the milliseconds and use a NSDateFormatter with a format string such as ssssssssssszzzzz and go from there. The formatter will deal with the time zone accordingly

Comment: ya, I got date also by this format. if time zone is changed. i need to write code for this. but it is not dynamic. this problem may have different solution.